# Error "typeLength 19 should be in range (1-16) for a long decimal" when upgraded hudi and spark versions when reading decimal from trino

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, trino, apache-hudi

I have upgraded AWS EMR version from 6.10 to 6.12 which now uses spark 3.4 version. I am ingesting data into hive/trino from csv. Spark job ingests data fine without any error, table is also created fine in trino.

Issue: When I query any other column except decimal column, query works fine. But when I query decimal column, it throws error.

Here is my decimal field in avro schema being used:

```
{"name":"myDecimalColumn",
"type":["null",
    {"type":"bytes",
        "scale":2,
        "precision":19,
        "connect.version":1,
        "connect.parameters":{"scale":"2","connect.decimal.precision":"19"},
        "connect.name":"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
        "logicalType":"decimal"}
    ],
"default":null}
```

Spark version: 3.4.0
Hudi version: 13.1

**Query**: select * from decimalColumn from tableName;
**Error**:

```
Caused by: io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.FailureInfo$FailureException: Failed to read Parquet file: s3://database/mytable/partCol=2023-07-01/d0d72ed9-949f-4f85-b61b-ed099656503e-0_1-6-8_20230905052437462.parquet
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSource.handleException(ParquetPageSource.java:200) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.parquet.ParquetPageSourceFactory.lambda$createPageSource$2(ParquetPageSourceFactory.java:290) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:75) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.project.DictionaryAwarePageProjection$DictionaryAwarePageProjectionWork.setupDictionaryBlockProjection(DictionaryAwarePageProjection.java:207) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.project.DictionaryAwarePageProjection$DictionaryAwarePageProjectionWork.lambda$getResult$0(DictionaryAwarePageProjection.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.project.PageProcessor$ProjectSelectedPositions.processBatch(PageProcessor.java:361) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.project.PageProcessor$ProjectSelectedPositions.process(PageProcessor.java:220) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$flatten$6(WorkProcessorUtils.java:318) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:360) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:347) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$BlockingProcess.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$flatten$6(WorkProcessorUtils.java:318) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:360) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:347) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$processStateMonitor$2(WorkProcessorUtils.java:241) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$finishWhen$3(WorkProcessorUtils.java:256) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorSourceOperatorAdapter.getOutput(WorkProcessorSourceOperatorAdapter.java:146) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:402) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$process$8(Driver.java:305) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:701) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processForDuration(Driver.java:268) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:888) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:187) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:561) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_414____20230829_054347_2.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: io.trino.jdbc.$internal.client.FailureInfo$FailureException: typeLength 19 should be in range (1-16) for a long decimal
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:193) ~[guava-14.0.1.jar:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.decoders.PlainValueDecoders$LongDecimalPlainValueDecoder.<init>(PlainValueDecoders.java:284) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.decoders.ValueDecoders.getFixedWidthLongDecimalDecoder(ValueDecoders.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.decoders.ValueDecoders.getLongDecimalDecoder(ValueDecoders.java:113) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.AbstractColumnReader.createValueDecoder(AbstractColumnReader.java:108) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.flat.FlatColumnReader.readFlatPageV1(FlatColumnReader.java:293) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.flat.FlatColumnReader.readPage(FlatColumnReader.java:255) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.flat.FlatColumnReader.readNextPage(FlatColumnReader.java:226) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.flat.FlatColumnReader.readNonNull(FlatColumnReader.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.flat.FlatColumnReader.readPrimitive(FlatColumnReader.java:84) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readPrimitive(ParquetReader.java:440) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readColumnChunk(ParquetReader.java:525) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.readBlock(ParquetReader.java:508) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetReader.lambda$nextPage$3(ParquetReader.java:273) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.parquet.reader.ParquetBlockFactory$ParquetBlockLoader.load(ParquetBlockFactory.java:72) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.project.DictionaryAwarePageProjection$DictionaryAwarePageProjectionWork.setupDictionaryBlockProjection(DictionaryAwarePageProjection.java:207) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.project.DictionaryAwarePageProjection$DictionaryAwarePageProjectionWork.lambda$getResult$0(DictionaryAwarePageProjection.java:195) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.load(LazyBlock.java:406) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock$LazyData.getFullyLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:385) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.spi.block.LazyBlock.getLoadedBlock(LazyBlock.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.project.PageProcessor$ProjectSelectedPositions.processBatch(PageProcessor.java:361) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.project.PageProcessor$ProjectSelectedPositions.process(PageProcessor.java:220) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$flatten$6(WorkProcessorUtils.java:318) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:360) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:347) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$BlockingProcess.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$flatten$6(WorkProcessorUtils.java:318) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:360) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$3.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:347) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$processStateMonitor$2(WorkProcessorUtils.java:241) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.getNextState(WorkProcessorUtils.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils.lambda$finishWhen$3(WorkProcessorUtils.java:256) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorUtils$ProcessWorkProcessor.process(WorkProcessorUtils.java:413) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.WorkProcessorSourceOperatorAdapter.getOutput(WorkProcessorSourceOperatorAdapter.java:146) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:402) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.lambda$process$8(Driver.java:305) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:701) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.process(Driver.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.operator.Driver.processForDuration(Driver.java:268) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:888) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:187) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:561) ~[?:?]
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_414____20230829_054347_2.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.j
```